# Proving a certain language is regular by constructing a DFA

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata

Let $L$ be a regular language over the alphabet $\sum$, prove that the language defined by $\hat{L} = \{uv \in \sum^* | u^Rv \in L \}$ is regular.

There is guidance in the exercise that instructs us to define for every $p \in Q$ the language:
$L_p = \{uv\in\sum^* | \delta(q_0,u^R) = p \space\space and \space\space \delta(p,v) \in F \}$
Then prove $L_p$ is regular and then deduce that $\hat{L}$ is also regular.
The last step is clear to me, that is $L = \bigcup_{p\in Q}L_p$ is a finite union of regular languages and therefore $L$ is regular.
Now, in order to prove $L_p$ is regular I tried to construct 2 DFAs:
Let $p\in Q$ and let us define 2 DFAs $B_q = (\sum,Q,p,q_0,\delta')$ and $C_q=(\sum,Q,p,F,\delta)$ and $\delta'(q',\sigma) = q$ if $\delta(q,\sigma) = q'$ (i.e. changing the directions of the arrows), from here it follows that $B_p$ recognizes all the words starting in state $p$ and ending in $q_0$, that is the reversion of the words that would be accepted if they were starting at $q_0$ and ending in $p$.
Similarly, $C_p$ recognizes all the words that start in state $p$ and end in $F$, therefore I can say that $L_p = L(B_p)*L(C_p)$ and therefore $L_p$ is regular.
I don't feel 100% confident about my proposal because I am unsure if I built the DFAs as they should be, more specifically I am not sure how to show that $B_q$ indeed recognizes the reversed strings ?
I will also be grateful if there's anyone who's able to guide me towards a different solution if such one exists
Source : The Open University of Israel, Computational Models course, https://mega.nz/folder/0Sg0iD4B#0OPF1JJgFjtYoJuStlsCtA/file/JbYXTYYS

Comment: What is your question?  I don't see a question here.  This is a question-and-answer site, so we require you to articulate a specific question -- hopefully, one that will be useful to others in the future.  A question normally ends with a "?".  If you're wondering whether your approach is correct, the usual approach is to see if you can write a proof of correctness.

Comment: @D.W. Edited my question

Comment: One way to prove that a DFA is correct is to use induction (on the length of the string).  I suggest giving that a try.

Comment: Your approach is basically OK. Note that your $B_p$, reversing the arrows, is no longer deterministic. That is not a problem as we do not need determinism at this point. It is relatively easy to argue the reverse strings are accepted: the accepting paths are simply reversed. (The general construction for the reverse of a regular language is slightly more involved as there might be several final states, thus several initial in reverse. Here we deal with one $p$ at a time.)